# Node js app keeps logging out the user when hosted on Google cloud

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, passport.js

I have a node js app which I am currently hosting on a heroku server and which is running fine. I have tried to deploy the same app on Google cloud to see how it performs there, but the thing is that the app requires for the users to be logged in first in order to use it, and for this I am using the passport npm which uses cookies to store the session's id in the browser.

The problem is that sometimes I can log in but sometimes I am not able to... and when I do log in, and try to access another link that requests access, the application doesn't recognize that I am already logged in and it automatically sends me back to the main page to log in...

Does anyone have a clue how I can fix the app to run as intended on Google Cloud?

Thank you.

Comment: This is your cookies issue then. Check your cookies. It is not google cloud issue

Comment: Thank you, I will do it right away.

Comment: Hi @InderRSingh,
This is how my app is set up so far... It keeps logging me out.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
......
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
app.use(session({
  secret: 'tesla',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  // cookie: {
  //   secure: 'auto'
  // }
}));


app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

Thank you.

Comment: I have tried to "force" my way and clicked multiple times the Login button and it works at some point...and it looks like it also works (but not every time) for the other Menu Links that require authentication ..